# windowSoftInputMode issue

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

this is my app main activity:

[image]

when SoftKeyboard opens my LinearLayout goes upward and my UI collaps, like this:
[image]

i use *android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"* and all of other parameters but there is no any change and my problem still here! when my screen is full screen everything works fine but when i change it to *android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"* this problem appears. i test it on Samsung Nexus S and Samsung Galaxy Ace. i search a full day about it! some people have this problem but there is no solution!!

Comment: you have to choose between pan and resize. it doesn't make any sense to use both.

Comment: i use pan and resize seperately too but there is no any change

Comment: the second image looks like the bg image is resized, which is supposed to happen it you use adjustResize. Are you sure you don't set it somewhere else?

Comment: yes,if i dont user resize adjust still my problem here! even with default setting

Answer (score 0):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

Comment: adjustNothing does not available! i get this error:
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'windowSoftInputMode' with value 'adjustNothing').

Comment: Yup me too.. it wont compile at all.. maybe we use an sdk or something that doesnt support this?